# Finding nested hash in hashes of JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

The JSON structure I have is as follows:

```
{
"result": {
    "status": 1,
    "num_results": 100,
    "total_results": 500,
    "results_remaining": 400,
    "matches": [
        {
            "match_id": 381440228,
            "match_seq_num": 347730324,
            "start_time": 1384292236,
            "lobby_type": 0
        },
        {
            "match_id": 380304327,
            "match_seq_num": 346687624,
            "start_time": 1384203633,
            "lobby_type": 0
        }
                    ]
```

There would be many more "matches" underneath that.

What I'm wondering is how I would pull one of the hashes in the 'matches' array by its 'match_id'.

Since the match_id is inside the hash, how would I pull the *entire* hash by searching for that value?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
hash["result"]["matches"].select {|m| m["match_id"] == match_id }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
hash["result"]["matches"].find { |m| m["match_id"] == "your id here" }
```

See [Enumberable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).